# jQuery keyup or blur with accounting.js

Tags: jquery, accounting.js

I am using [accounting.js](http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js) (along with [bindWithDelay.js](http://briangrinstead.com/files/bindWithDelay/)) to format a number on keyup or blur. The issue is that when I input in the textbox the second time to modify the number, the plugin formats the number incorrectly the second time.

For example, if I enter the number `28,1`, accounting.js formats it this way `28,10`. This is the expected output. But when I modify the number the second time to `28.16`, accounting.js formats it again to `2.816,00` which is not the intended result.

This is the code:

JS:

```
accounting.settings = {
        number: {
            precision : 2,  // default precision on numbers is 0
            thousand: ".",
            decimal : ","
        }
    }

        $(".c").bindWithDelay("keyup", function() {
            $(this).val(accounting.formatNumber($(this).val()));
        }, 2000);
```

HTML:

```
<input class="c" type="text" id="height" name="height" value=""  />
```

Comment: As I see it from their demo page, this is the expected outcome. It just assumes, that you put the `.` in the wrong place and reformats the number to be `2.816` and then appends the decimal places to the end result `2.816,00`. It does not convert the `.` to `,` if it's in the wrong place. If I enter `0.34` it converts the number to `34,00`.

Comment: @Christoph, is there anyway I can prevent this behaviour?

Comment: I have no idea. I just took a quick look at their documentation. You should try to contact the devs.